# How to copy files into a virtual box oracle box

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using oracle box with windows and I have to keep re-plugging in my usb for it to recognise.  I want to copy files into the virtual machine but it does not let me do this so this is what I have resorted to.

In general settings I Have enabled shared  clipboard and drag n drop.

I've found it's easier just using my laptop for testing but this is just not as convenient.  Strangely, my linux OS in my VM works fine and can copy and paste into it from my main os.  How do I allow copy and paste for windows?   I'm current doing a reinstall of   windows os on vm and seeing if that helps.

My question, how do I copy and paste into virtual box with windows.  Failing that, how can I get my virtual box to recognise my usb without replugging it in and out all the time.  Either workaround is useful.

Comment: My workaround is to just use Google Drive or whatever cloud drive you have for the sharing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nice solution could be to share a directory on your host machine with the virtual machine, so you can copy your files in and out.

Look at: 
[How to share your computer files with a virtual machine](https://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: I will try that.  This has been bothering me for some time.  Hopefully this will mean no more slow af laptop testing.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a menu when I click devices -> insert guest additions.  Because it does nothing.

Comment: I think it should pop up a window to install the guest additions in the VM. If it does not, goto "This PC" on the VM, try to double click the DVD Drive or to open it and look for some installation files

Comment: This is sweet.  Never could get into Virtual box because of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just create ISO file from folder and then mount, or copy files to USB Stick and then mount to VM

[Folder2Iso](https://folder2iso.en.softonic.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way I found is to use Google Drive. Other options include: OneDrive, Dropbox, Email, etc.